# How can I make my SI (Supplementary Information) with numbers (currently: using the appendix package)?

Tags: sectioning, appendix

I want to have my "appendix" to be a supplementary information - but instead of just renaming it `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Supplementary Information}` I also want it to be numbered:

Supplementary Information 1 (section)

Supplementary Information 2 (section)

Supplementary Information 2.1 (subsection)

Supplementary Information 2.2 (subsection)

I thought this numbering where easy, just: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` but as you can see, this did not do the trick.

I am very limited, because I need to use this weird format/documentclass, see below:

```
[![\documentclass\[preprint,12pt,authoryear\]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tocbibind} %for appendix/SI numbering
\usepackage\[toc,page\]{appendix} %for appendix/SI numbering

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\def\COMP#1{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\myMatrix}\[1\]{\bm{\mathit{#1}}}

\doublespacing

\journal{x}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{A title}
\author{Me}

\begin{keyword}
A keyword
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}




\section{Introduction \label{sec:intro}}

Please find some text here. Find more of my ideas in~\ref{sec:si1}.


\section{Conclusion \label{sec:concl}}
Main text is over.
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Supplementary Information}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}


\appendix

%\section*{Supplementary Information}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{SI~\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{SI~\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{table}{0}

\section{The first thing in SI
 \label{sec:si1}}
word
\section{The second thing in SI}
another word
\subsection{The first sub-thing in SI}
bla bla
\subsection{The second sub-thing in SI}
bla bla 2


\end{document}][1]][1]
```

[image: this is the current outcome in picture]

Comment: What happens if you comment this "\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}" and set counter section as 0 before the first section in SI?

Comment: This is probably the same answer as above, so also right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the numbering change *after*, not *before*, the `\appendix` command. Below is a modified version of your MWE where I have changed all your `\[` and `\]` to the regular `[` and `]` so that it will compile using `pdflatex`.

```
% appsiprob.tex  SE 575134

\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tocbibind} %for appendix/SI numbering
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} %for appendix/SI numbering

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\def\COMP#1{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\myMatrix}[1]{\bm{\mathit{#1}}}

\doublespacing

\journal{x}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{A title}
\author{Me}

\begin{keyword}
A keyword
\end{keyword}

%\tableofcontents
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction \label{sec:intro}}

Please find some text here. Find more of my ideas in~\ref{sec:si1}.

\section{Conclusion \label{sec:concl}}
Main text is over.
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Supplementary Information}

%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}   %%%% not here
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Supplementary Information \arabic{section}}    %%%% but here

%\section*{Supplementary Information}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{SI~\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{SI~\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{table}{0}

\section{The first thing in SI
 \label{sec:si1}}
word
\section{The second thing in SI}
another word
\subsection{The first sub-thing in SI}
bla bla
\subsection{The second sub-thing in SI}
bla bla 2

\end{document}][1]][1]
```

I didn't change the weird stuff after your `\end{document}` as that would be ignored by `pdflatex`.

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, thanks a lot! Some of the weird things came from posting here (as I didn't find them in the document I had copy pasted).